# How to do a docker cp (copy) and replace directory on copy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, copy

I want to copy a directory named `custom-data-src` to my docker container

Command:

```bash
docker cp custom-data-src/.  <container_name>/data/custom-data-dest
```

The code above copies the files of `custom-data-src` but does not completely replace `/data/custom-data-dest`.

For example, I want `custom-data-dest` to have the same files as `custom-data-src`. When I remove a file from `custom-data-src` and run the command again, the file won't be removed from `custom-data-dest`. To summarize, I basically want a copy and replace of the directory when I run the command.

Any help or direction is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `docker cp` here?  Are you maybe looking for the Dockerfile `COPY` directive, where an image built always starts from a clean environment?  Or a bind mount, if it's a data directory?